# AngularJS - Cannot get height of an element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I cannot get the height of an rendered element. It returns null. I need the element to check its height it self without user interaction.

HTML

```
<span ng-if="contentHeight($element)" ></span>
```

JS

```
    $scope.contentHeight = function(element){
        console.log($(element).height());
        return true;
    };
```

Comment: Is your element actually displayed ? Measuring elements that are invisible is kinda tricky.

Comment: Where does $element come from?, tried to log $(element)?

Comment: @Bartdude yes it is displayed

Comment: Are you using a directive for this, if not you should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might work better for you if you use a directive here because it passes the element into the directive itself.

HTML

```
<span class="directive"></span>
```

JS

```
app.directive('directive', function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            console.log($(element).height());
        }
    }
});
```

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but that might solve your problem :)

**Edit:** added documentation! https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive